# Why is there no RichMapFunction in pyflink?

Tags: pyflink

There is pyflink.datastream.MapFunction in Flink Python API Docs. Meanwhile there is no RichMapFunction. Could somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the functions in PyFlink are rich. You can see that, `pyflink.datastream.MapFunction` extends `pyflink.datastream.Function` which has a `open` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's missing from PyFlink, but RichMapFunction is completely unnecessary. Anything you could do with a RichMapFunction can be done with a ProcessFunction or KeyedProcessFunction instead.